# Add different values to a list without becoming a tuple

Tags: python, list

I have a list of machines. Each machine has a workload and a workspeed.
The workload is the same for every machine, but the workspeed is different on each machine.

```
all_machines = []
for i in range(number_of_machines):
    all_machines.append(Machine(0, 0.5), Machine(0, 1.0), Machine(0, 1.5))
```

if I do it this way, the list `all_machines` becomes a tuple. But it needs to be a list.

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

How can I code it the way that it stays as a list and does not become a tuple?

Comment: TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

This is the error i am getting.

Comment: Then i get the same error "TypeError: list.extend() takes exactly one argument (3 given)"

Comment: `list.extend()` expects an iterable collection, like shown in the dup answer.

Answer (score 1):

The method `.append()` can only take one item at a time. You should use the `.extend()` method instead.